# Subset NAs between values

Tags: r, subset, na

I would like to know how I could only subset NAs excluding those that are on the extremes of a vector.

For instance,

`vector <- c(NA,NA,1,3,5,NA,3,NA,7,NA,NA,NA)`

How could I only subset the NAs vector[6] and vector[8]?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by *subset*? Can you show us your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get indices which are not on extremes is

```
non_NA_inds <- which(!is.na(vector))
NA_inds <- which(is.na(vector))
NA_inds[NA_inds > min(non_NA_inds) & NA_inds < max(non_NA_inds)]
#[1] 6 8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code

```
idx <- which(!is.na(vector))
res <- setdiff(min(idx):max(idx),idx)
```

which gives:

```
> res
[1] 6 8
```